# dynamodb batchget projection per item

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

As per http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html
In dynamodb batchget api request syntax there is a ProjectionExpression . It is applied to all items . Can I specify projectionexpression per item in batch get items.
say need attr1,attr2 from item1
and attr3,attr4 from item2.

Can I use batchGet? item1 and item2 have different primary and sortkey.

Answer (score 0):

`RequestItems` is a map of table names to get requests. If you are trying to get items from two different tables (which it sounds like you are doing) then you would have two `RequestItems` map entries. Each `RequestItems` entry would have a unique `ProjectionExpression` value.

It would look something like this:

```
{
   "RequestItems": { 
      "table1" : { 
         "AttributesToGet": [ "string" ],
         "ConsistentRead": boolean,
         "ExpressionAttributeNames": { 
            "string" : "string" 
         },
         "Keys": [ 
            { 
               ...
            }
         ],
         "ProjectionExpression": "string"
      },
      "table2" : { 
         "AttributesToGet": [ "string" ],
         "ConsistentRead": boolean,
         "ExpressionAttributeNames": { 
            "string" : "string" 
         },
         "Keys": [ 
            { 
               ...
            }
         ],
         "ProjectionExpression": "string"
      }
   }
   "ReturnConsumedCapacity": "string"
}
```

Comment: I am getting items from single table..Can I give multiple projection string . Each is different for each key(Item) of same table ?

Comment: I don't think you can.